# Extracting table tag values using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, html-table, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to write a Python script to extract some tag values from within a table located on this page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/

I've included a screenshot of the HTML source code, however I can't figure out how to extract the price data for columns 6,7,8 and 9. Below is the code I've already written.

```html
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

table1 = soup.find_all('table', class_= 'sd-table')

#writing the first few columns to text file

with open('examplefile.txt', 'w') as r:
    for row in table1.find_all('tr'):
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
            r.write(cell.text.ljust(5))
        r.write('\n')
```

I'm ultimately trying to extract out all of the values for each row and save it into a Pandas DataFrame, or a CSV. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table values seem to be embedded in a JSON string that can be gotten with [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads). Then we can get the value by indicating a `"regional"` key of country's region.

It's a bit more complicated but at least it gets the values that we put into a dataframe as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

# force maximum dataframe column width
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 0)

url = 'https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'row row-size3 column'})

region = 'us-west-2' # Adjust your region here

def parse_table_as_dataframe(table):
    data = []
    header = []
    c5 = c6 = c7 = c8 = []

    rows = []
    columns = []

    name = table.h3.text

    try:
        # This part gets the first word in each column header so the table
        # fits reasonably in the display, adjust to your preference 
        header = [h.text.split()[0].strip() for h in table.thead.find_all('th')][1::]
    except AttributeError:
        return 'N/A'

    for row in table.tbody.find_all('tr'):
        for c in row.find_all('td')[1::]:
            if c.text.strip() not in (u'', u'$-') :
                if 'dash' in c.text.strip():
                    columns.append('-') # replace "&dash; &dash:" with a `-`
                else:
                    columns.append(c.text.strip())  
            else:
                try:
                    data_text = c.span['data-amount']
                    # data = json.loads(data_text)['regional']['asia-pacific-southeast']
                    data = json.loads(data_text)['regional'][region]
                    columns.append(data)
                except (KeyError, TypeError):
                    columns.append('N/A')



    num_rows = len(table.tbody.find_all('tr'))
    num_columns = len(header)

    # For debugging
    # print(len(columns), columns)
    # print(num_rows, num_columns)

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(columns).reshape(num_rows, num_columns), columns=header)
    return df

for n, table in enumerate(tables):
    print(n, table.h3.text)
    print(parse_table_as_dataframe(table))
```

gets 24 dataframes, one for each table from the page:

```
0 B-series
  Instance Core        RAM Temporary    Pay      One    Three        3
0  B1S      1    1.00 GiB   2 GiB     0.017  0.01074  0.00838  0.00438
1  B2S      2    4.00 GiB   8 GiB     0.065  0.03483  0.02543  0.01743
2  B1MS     1    2.00 GiB   4 GiB     0.032  0.01747  0.01271  0.00871
3  B2MS     2    8.00 GiB   16 GiB    0.122  0.06165  0.04289  0.03489
4  B4MS     4    16.00 GiB  32 GiB    0.229  0.12331  0.08579  0.06979
5  B8MS     8    32.00 GiB  64 GiB    0.438  0.24661  0.17157  0.13957

...

...

23 H-series
  Instance Core         RAM  Temporary    Pay      One    Three        3
0  H8       8    56.00 GiB   1,000 GiB  1.129  0.90579  0.72101  0.35301
1  H16      16   112.00 GiB  2,000 GiB  2.258  1.81168  1.44205  0.70605
2  H8m      8    112.00 GiB  1,000 GiB  1.399  1.08866  0.84106  0.47306
3  H16m     16   224.00 GiB  2,000 GiB  2.799  2.17744  1.68212  0.94612
4  H16mr    16   224.00 GiB  2,000 GiB  3.012  2.32162  1.77675  1.04075
5  H16r     16   112.00 GiB  2,000 GiB  2.417  1.91933  1.51267  0.77667
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry about that error, i used the wrong print syntax, try again with the updated code

Comment: oh i noticed you wanted 4 columns, but I only got 3 columns... i will need to fix that too!

Comment: In my Jupyter notebook, the values aren't displayed as the table you posted above. On mine, it shows the three headings and then all of the values underneath, rather than as a table. any thoughts? Thanks a bunch for your help again!

Pay as you go
One year reserved
Three year reserved

and then all of the values underneath

Comment: sorry, I am struggling to write the answer in python3 syntax, but i've only got python2. will update

Comment: Please check updated code if you get correct output. thanks. Also, see demo here: https://repl.it/repls/FarflungAgileFlashmemory

Comment: How would I add the other columns (CPU, name, RAM,) before these columns,  then add in some of the other regions next to it, as well as for the other Virtual Machine types?

Comment: that will require more parsing work. I'll try to update with those features soon.

Comment: That would be great. I'm specifically looking for the Instance, CPU, RAM, and Storage capacity in front of those costs, but can't seem to get it formatted correctly. Essentially so the final solution looks identical to the table on the website, except for the "add to estimate" button with all of the tables below it

Comment: any update on this front? I'd like to at least get the vm machine name and replicate this process across all of the tables on the page

Comment: sorry for not getting back to you sooner. Are you using Python2 or Python3? I think i have a script that works for all tables, but seems to only work in python2, trying to update work in python3.

Comment: thanks! it worked for me. I ended up making a for loop to go through each of the regions and print out all of the data frames. The only issue I'm having now is with the tables that have (- - ) as their price or 'Not available', which makes the last table column get pushed to the next line. Is there any way to make those just display (-) instead of "&dash; &dash:" ?

Comment: yes i think we can check for '`dash`' and replace it with '`-`'. check the few lines I added

Comment: that worked, thanks! is there any way to get all of the columns on the same line? I see that some of them are getting pushed to a new line, id like all of the columns to have the same spacing (on the same line) across all of the tables

Comment: yes, but it may depend on what are you using to display the output (an IDE, `cmd.exe` command prompt, or some terminal emulator?) You may need to increase the buffer width of whatever it is you are using to display the output. I was using PowerShell terminal on windows, which required increasing the buffer size to about `80`.

Comment: sounds good, thanks. I modified the code to loop through all of the regions. Last question - how would I be able to export this entire dataframe into a CSV? since it is within the function in a loop, I can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Pandas can likely handle this on its own with [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html). You can then cleanup data types, etc. within the resulting frame. Returns an array of matches - here's the general idea:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/'

dfs = pd.read_html(url, attrs={'class':'sd-table'})

print dfs[0]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I ran that code, and unfortunately all of the prices still show up blank...is there any way I can extract those values?

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = find_all ('table', {'class':'sd-table'})
```

Comment: Hey there! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.